# как обрезать картинку средствами css

Tags: html, css, css3

Увидел где-то в ютубе рекламу дизайнера, и мне приглянулся один элемент с его сайта - обрезка картинки. При переходе на сайт бросается в глаза обрезанное изображение, при чём средствами css: на псевдоэлементе "after" есть селектор "border", и если его отключить, то обрезка с картинки уберется. Можете помочь разобратся что за что тут отвечает?
Сайт: https://alexeybychkov.com/
Те свойства:

```
border-top-color: transparent;
border-top-style: solid;
border-top-width: 280px;
border-right-color: transparent;
border-right-style: solid;
border-right-width: 3200px;
border-bottom-color: #fff;
border-bottom-style: solid;
border-bottom-width: 280px;
border-left-color: transparent;
border-left-style: solid;
border-left-width: 3200px;
border-image-source: initial;
border-image-slice: initial;
border-image-width: initial;
border-image-outset: initial;
border-image-repeat: initial;
```

Comment: На указанном вами сайте нет никакой обрезки, это всего лишь белый треугольник наложенный поверх картинки. А о том, как рисовать треугольники через border, в интернете уже рассказано кучу раз http://htmlbook.ru/blog/treugolniki-cherez-css

Comment: https://alligator.io/css/cropping-images-object-fit/ тут показано